# Use of COUNT to display distinct records with more than 2 occurrences in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table where I am trying to build a distinct list of all the cities with more than two occurrences in the table.  I am trying the current query am am told "function count does not exist"?  What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT COUNT (city) 
FROM `table1` 
GROUP BY city 
HAVING COUNT (city) >=2
```

Comment: While the solution described below is correct, I cannot replicate this error message.

Comment: i can replicate the problem here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66537/1 mysql is weird...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your query is correct you have given a space between `COUNT` and (City) it must be `COUNT(City)`. that will work fine. Your query should be like this:

```
SELECT City, COUNT(city) Counts
  FROM `table1` 
 GROUP BY City
HAVING COUNT(city) >=2;
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52db1/7)

Answer (score -1):

USE ALIAS

```
SELECT COUNT(city) as SOME_TEXT FROM table1 GROUP BY city HAVING SOME_TEXT >=2
```