# select values of a column which appear N times in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Evening all,
I want to select the values of column that appear exactly N times in the table. More specifically, I have 3 tables.

```
employees dept_emp departments
```

N = the number of rows of the table departments. I want all the emp_no (employees and dept_emp) that appear exactly N times at table dept_emp. I tried this

```
select e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name
from employees e, dept_emp de, departments d
where e.emp_no=de.emp_no
group by de.emp_no
having count(de.emp_no)=count(d.dept_no);
```

but doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're missing a join with departments table. Once you add that, then I believe that your query will return all employees who are the sole member of a deparatment: is that what you're trying to get?

Comment: Don't use implicit join syntax

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921464/use-of-count-to-display-distinct-records-with-more-than-2-occurrences-in-mysql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure of what you're asking for but does this help?

```
select e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name
from   employees e, dept_emp de
where  e.emp_no=de.emp_no
group by e.emp_no, e.first_name, e.last_name
having count(*) = (select count(*) from departments);
```

Comment: You generally have to group by every column that you want in the select column whether they make the row unique or not.  The only columns you don't need in the group by clause are those in aggregate functions like count(*) or max(column_name) etc.