# return values that occur ONLY thrice

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, distinct

I have a table that looks like this:

```
+-------+------+
|naming | year |
+-------+------|
|  A.   | 2003 |
|  B    | 1994 |
| B     | 1996 |
|  A.   | 2001 |
|  A.   | 2002 |
| A.    | 1999 |
| B.    | 1999 |

|  C.   | 2001 |
|  c.   | 2003 |
| C.    | 2002 |
```

I want to return all names that occur at least thrice and for which the year is consecutive. For example, here: C occurs thrice in conseucutive years (2001,2002, 2003) so I want to return C. However, I don't want to return A. because it occurs four times
and the fourth is not consuqetive.
How can I achieve this in sql?

If I do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM test AS t1
JOIN test AS t2 ON  t1.year = t2.year-1
JOIN test AS t3 ON  t1.year = t3.year-2
```

I will also get A even though it should not be included.

I am looking for another way to do this. Something that's also easily understandable. The multiple joins above are a bit confusing

Comment: "I will also get A" with your approach you can use it in join as well - ON  t1.year = t2.year-1 AND t1.naming = t2.naming

Comment: What if for X there are years 2000, 2001 and 2002 and also 2010, 2011, 2012?

Comment: it could be included then @forpas

Comment: What about a name with years 2010,2011,2012 and 2020,2021?  Then, do you want just the list of names that conform? Or all the rows for names that conform?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [select values of a column which appear N times in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24067123/select-values-of-a-column-which-appear-n-times-in-sql)

Answer (score 0):

Use `LAG()` and `SUM()` window functions and 2 levels of aggregation:

```
SELECT naming
FROM (
  SELECT naming, COUNT(*) count
  FROM (
    SELECT *, SUM(flag) OVER (PARTITION BY naming ORDER BY year) grp
    FROM (
      SELECT *, year - 1 IS NOT LAG(year) OVER (PARTITION BY naming ORDER BY year) flag
      FROM tablename
    )
  )
  GROUP BY naming, grp
)
GROUP BY naming
HAVING MIN(count) >= 3;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=58e401ee8f454e2d7eed2eeb235f37c3).